# How to redirect back to the edit route, If something goes wrong with the update route?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http, mongoose

I have some edit form at the route "/someDbDocumentId/edit" and if some user goes there but messes up with the documentId(using chrome inspection tool or similar) in the form 'action' attribute before submitting the form, then i want to redirect the user back to the edit form and display some error message there.But in my code, i can redirect the user to the edit form only if the id is correct and not messed up. How can i do that? Or is there any other way to redirect the user back?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass just id in your route please check below comment :

```
 res.redirect(namedRouter.urlFor('service.edit', { id: serviceId }));
```

here "service.edit" is your route name